# when i click update button error show user update failed ``

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern, put

`1.` **userRoute.js code is**  router.put('/update/:id' , user.update)
1.

1. **userControler.js code is**
2. 
3. exports.update = async (req, res) => {
4. const { fullname, homeAddress, barberAddress } = req.body;
5. const { id } = req.params;
6. console.log('Received ID:', id); // Add this line
7. try {
8. Find and update the user by ID
9. const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
10. id,
11. ```
      {
    ```
12. fullname,
13. homeAddress,
14. barberAddress,
15. ```
      },
    ```
16. ```
      {
    ```
17. new: true,
18. ```
      }
    ```
19. ```
    );
    ```
20. 
21. if (!updatedUser) {
22. User not found, return a 404 response
23. return res.status(404).json({ message: 'User not found' });
24. ```
    }
    ```
25. User was updated successfully
26. res.json(updatedUser);
27. catch (error) {
28. console.error('Error updating user:', error);
29. res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' });
30. }
31. };
32. 
33. 
34. **UserEditForm.js is **
35. 
36. import axios from 'axios';
37. import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
38. import { useNavigate, useParams, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
39. import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
40. import * as Yup from 'yup';
41. 
42. export default function UserEdit() {
43. const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
44. const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({
45. fullname: '',
46. homeAddress: '',
47. barberAddress: '',
48. });
49. const initialValues = formValues;
50. 
51. const { id } = useParams();
52. const navigate = useNavigate();
53. 
54. useEffect(() => {
55. Fetch user data
56. const fetchUserData = async () => {
57. try {
58. const response = await axios.get(`/user/${id}`);
59. if (response.data) {
60. setUserData(response.data); // Set the fetched user data in state
61. setFormValues({
62. fullname: response.data.fullname,
63. homeAddress: response.data.homeAddress,
64. barberAddress: response.data.barberAddress,
65. ```
          });
    ```
66. ```
        }
    ```
67. catch (error) {
68. console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
69. ```
      }
    ```
70. ```
    };
    ```
71. 
72. fetchUserData();
73. []);
74. 
75. const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
76. fullname: Yup.string().required('Full name is required'),
77. homeAddress: Yup.string().required('Home address is required'),
78. barberAddress: Yup.string().required('Barber address is required'),
79. });
80. const handleSubmit = async (values, { setSubmitting, setFieldError }) => {
81. try {
82. const response = await axios.put(`/update/${id}`, {
83. fullname: values.fullname,
84. homeAddress: values.homeAddress,
85. barberAddress: values.barberAddress,
86. ```
      });
    ```
87. 
88. console.log('User updated successfully:', response.data);
89. setSubmitting(false);
90. window.alert('User updated successfully!');
91. Redirect to the user list page
92. navigate('/admin/users/list');
93. catch (error) {
94. console.error('User update failed:', error);
95. setSubmitting(false);
96. 
97. if (error.response) {
98. Handle specific error responses here
99. const { data } = error.response;
100. if (data && data.errors) {
101. Set form field errors based on the response
102. data.errors.forEach((error) => {
103. setFieldError(error.field, error.message);
104. ```
           });
     ```
105. ```
         }
     ```
106. else {
107. Handle general network or server errors here
108. window.alert('An error occurred while updating the user.');
109. ```
       }
     ```
110. ```
     }
     ```
111. };
112. console.log(
113. formValues
114. )
115. return (
116. ```
     <div className="Register-form-container">
     ```
117. ```
       <Formik
     ```
118. initialValues={formValues}
119. validationSchema={validationSchema}
120. onSubmit={handleSubmit}
121. ```
       >
     ```
122. isSubmitting }) => (
123. ```
           <Form className="Register-form">
     ```
124. ```
             <div className="Register-form-content">
     ```
125. ```
               <h3 className="Register-form-title">User Edit Form</h3>
     ```
126. ```
               <div className="form-group mt-3">
     ```
127. ```
                 <label htmlFor="fullname">Full Name</label>
     ```
128. ```
                 <Field
     ```
129. value={formValues?.fullname||''}
130. 
131. type="text"
132. name="fullname"
133. className="form-control mt-1"
134. placeholder="Full Name"
135. ```
                 />
     ```
136. ```
                 <ErrorMessage name="fullname" component="div" className="text-danger" />
     ```
137. ```
               </div>
     ```
138. ```
               <div className="form-group mt-3">
     ```
139. ```
                 <label htmlFor="homeAddress">Home Address</label>
     ```
140. ```
                 <Field
     ```
141. 
142. defaultValue={formValues?.homeAddress}
143. 
144. type="text"
145. name="homeAddress"
146. className="form-control mt-1"
147. placeholder="Home Address"
148. ```
                 />
     ```
149. ```
                 <ErrorMessage name="homeAddress" component="div" className="text-danger" />
     ```
150. ```
               </div>
     ```
151. ```
               <div className="form-group mt-3">
     ```
152. ```
                 <label htmlFor="barberAddress">Barber Address</label>
     ```
153. ```
                 <Field
     ```
154. defaultValue={formValues?.barberAddress}
155. 
156. type="text"
157. name="barberAddress"
158. className="form-control mt-1"
159. placeholder="Barber Address"
160. ```
                 />
     ```
161. ```
                 <ErrorMessage name="barberAddress" component="div" className="text-danger" />
     ```
162. ```
               </div>
     ```
163. 
164. ```
               <div className="d-grid gap-2 mt-3">
     ```
165. ```
                 <button
     ```
166. type="submit"
167. className="btn btn-primary"
168. disabled={isSubmitting}
169. ```
                 >
     ```
170. ```
                   {isSubmitting ? 'Updating...' : 'Update User'}
     ```
171. ```
                 </button>
     ```
172. ```
                 <Link to="/admin/users/list" className="btn btn-secondary">
     ```
173. Cancel
174. ```
                 </Link>
     ```
175. ```
               </div>
     ```
176. ```
             </div>
     ```
177. ```
           </Form>
     ```
178. ```
         )}
     ```
179. ```
       </Formik>
     ```
180. 
181. ```
     </div>
     ```
182. );
183. }
184. 
185. 
186. when i click update button error show user update failed ``

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).